# adding the selected text on the webpage inside a field in an injected sidebar chrome extension when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hi so i have a chrome extension which injects a sidebar when clicked.What I want is if I select a location on a webpage and then click on the extension, it automatically fills the location input bar with the selected text and call the Maps API inside the iframe with the location name as query.

Comment: When you post a question, please clean your code and delete unused line (like commented function calls). It's a litle hard to read...

Comment: Not the source of your problem but you have to know that `chrome.tabs.getSelected()` is deprecated since Chrome 33. Instead you have to use [chrome.tabs.query()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query) ( like this in your case : `chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, callback);`)

Answer (score 1):

I have seen some problems in the code.

#### Background.js

`var place = window.getSelection().toString()` should not be placed here. You can't have selected text in the background page. You can remove this line.

Like said in comment, You should replace the depracated `chrome.tabs.getSelected`
by `chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, callback);`, read more about this function [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query).

#### Script.js

The smelling code is the `handleRequest` function. You have made to condition, the first doing nothing, and the second, if I have well understood, displaying the sidebar.

So I think the problem is here. You should move the `place = window.getSelection().toString();` statement to the first condition and then call `sendResponse({data : place})`. This way, you should send back the text selected in the page to the background script.

```
function handleRequest(request, sender, sendResponse)
{
    if (request.method == "getSelection")
    {
       place = window.getSelection().toString();
       console.log("sending to background : " + place);
       sendResponse({data: place});
    }

    if (request.callFunction == "toggleSidebar")
    {
       toggleSidebar();
       console.log("adasda");
    }
}
```

#### All code

You should do a clean up. There is lot of not usefull comment that you should remove. It will improve the readability of your code for a better debuging.